# Kubernetes - HTTP Probe failed with statuscode: 404

Tags: kubernetes

I`ve got a specyfic problem. When the container is running in Pods, the application contained in it works correctly, while in kubernetes the status is displayed - Error. In Events there are the following problems:

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP Probe failed with statuscode: 404
Liveness probe failed: HTTP Probe failed with statuscode: 404
```

The same errors are displayed in four containers with applications (Spring Boot). On the other hand, when I launch a container with a simple application (writing numbers from 0 to 10), in Kuberneres, the status is success. I'm just learning a Kubernetes, so I'd like to ask for help, which may be the cause of the problems?

Comment: add the pod yaml

Comment: Which endpoint are you calling for your probe? Do you have something mapped on that endpoint?

Comment: yes there could be a reason the health path doesn't correctly defined into deployment.yaml or defined the properly with probe values like initalDelay, it could be a reason your container still is being in ready state.
you could do to check the health path with curl command (linux) with localhost inside the container

Answer (score 7):

check liveness probe and readiness probe in your deployment yml. Check the path is correct. if still not resolved increase the initialDelay seconds